# partition showing on "sudo fdisk -l" but not on ubuntu or windows

Tags: partitioning

it's my first post , so please indulge me .

I am mainly a windows user but getting my hands on Ubuntu .

My problem is when i run " sudo fdisk -l" this is the result

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2bfb4dc8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       718848 245762047 245043200 116,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       245762048 878535144 632773097 301,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       878536702 976771071  98234370  46,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       878536704 960231423  81694720    39G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       960233472 976771071  16537600   7,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

My issue is with the partition 4 , it does not show on file explorer ,  when i try to reinstall ubuntu from the start , and not when i try to reinstall windows , basically , it's like that partition does not exist .

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys , running Gparted , i figured it out , this is what i get running gparted

[image]